# WP and Laravel integration (Updated)

Tags: php, theme-development

My client had a booking train tickets web developed full (app, frontend, and backend) in Laravel.
He contacts me because he wants to move to WordPress.
I've had the site working full-on WP but I've problems with the app.
He asked me to keep his old app (the booking tickets one).

The frontend has a typical travel form (where/to/passengers/datepicker) and when you complete the fields, it takes you to continue the booking process.
The Laravel app does it, but I need to know if a can integrate the booking part of the app with the front and backend in WordPress.

UPDATE:

I've made some research and I've found that I can modify the public.php on Laravel and I can use the frontend of WordPress with the original backend, and this (https://github.com/jgrossi/corcel) allows to use Laravel with WP backend.

Does anybody know if it's possible to mix both of them?

(Sorry for my English, it's not my native language)

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

There is no "generic" way to just smash WP with another app and have it work.

It can be roughly split in two cases:

1. Applications run separately on server, installed in different directories, and styled to look as one site (possibly talking to same database, possibly talking to each other via REST API or something).
2. One of the applications runs whole site (URLs, routing, templates, styles, etc) and incorporates another in PHP runtime to perform specific functionality.

It is hard to advise on specific case without thorough research into circumstances.

In general WP *is* a PHP runtime and integrating other PHP solutions with it is perfectly possible.

Comment: The second case sounds more like a need to do now (or, actually, what my client needs).
I don't know if in the future my client is going to keep the site I'm developing now or is going to make a new one (full WP, full Laravel, whatever) so, in words, it looks easier to me to develope in that way.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since both wordpress and laravel will most likely try to take control from each other. The best way to do such integration is by defining restful API to the laravel part, and use the `wp_get_remote` family of functions to retrieve information.

In the long term it is probably a suboptimal solution for people that do not have a permanent developer on a payrole as it means that there are two different code bases to maintain which makes maintenance (and hiring the right freelancers) more complex.

Comment: I've search more information and I get this:
https://github.com/Cyber-Duck/laravel-wp-api/blob/master/README.md

It's something like what you've answered?

Reading that file I assume that makes what I've need, calling the WordPress files (posts, pages, etc.).